# Angular - how to show progress percentage while building the application

Tags: angular-cli

After upgrading to Angular 11, it seems the percentage of the building process doesn't show. In the previous versions, Angular had buildings like this in the old versions:

[image]

I tried --progress flag but still, it doesn't show me the building percentage like the previous versions. Here is the Angular 11 building in the terminal:

[image]

Any suggestions to have the progress percentage while building?